# No StartUp Object In Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I created two classes with main methods and got "Program has more than one entry points" error

**First Class**

[image]

**Second Class**
[image]

But still no startup object shows in the list

**No StartUp Object**
[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, please edit your question with your code so anyone that can help you can easily reproduce your problem.

Comment: Change one of them so it's not main.

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/77772/cannot-select-startup-object-for-multiple-classes.html).  The "mostly fixed" promise is an exaggeration.  Code accordingly.